# Split string by commas using istringstream

Tags: c++, split, istringstream

I tried this code which can split the string by comma:

```
string spa ="12,233,434,2";
istringstream iss(spa + ",");
int val;
char dot =',';
while(iss >> val >> dot){
     cout << val << endl;
}
```

But I have no idea how it works. It seems to extract the value firstly, then right-shifts?

Comment: ps: It seems no matter what the char is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iss >> val >> dot` reads an `int` and a `char`, which happens to match the format of the input.

Their values prior to reading doesn't matter at all.

The `while` tests if the read was successful, and stops when the input fails.